# Proving that a complex number $z$ is real.

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

A problem I have in my book is to prove that $z$ is real if and only if $\bar{z} = z$.

So far I have got that for $z = x + iy$, if $z$ is real, $y = 0$ and thus $z = x = \bar{z}$ as  $\bar{z} = x - iy$ where $y = 0$ (if I'm right).

Now my book mentions something like converse of this, i.e, if $\bar{z} = z$ then $x+iy = x-iy$, where the last equality implies $y = -y$ and thus $y = 0$ (I don't get what equality it's talking about).

Also later it's explained that, therefore, $z = x$ and thus is real. (I don't get the second part at all).

Can someone please help me to understand this?

Comment: Notice that two complex numbers $a+ib$ and $x+iy$ are equal iff $a=x$ and $b=y$. Now what can you conclude from $x+iy = x-iy$ ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

let $z=x+iy$  where, $x,y∈\mathbb{R}$
First assume that we are given $z$ is real then its imaginary part must be equal to $0$
Therefore, $z=x$.
Now, assume that $z=\overline{z}$ where  $\overline{z}=x-iy$
then, $$x+iy=x-iy$$ $$iy=-iy$$ $$2y=0$$  that means $y=o$ .
So,we get, $z=x$.

Answer (score 4):

Notice that when we are saying two complex number are equal, we mean that both the real parts and imaginary parts of the two numbers are equal. So $$z=\bar{z}\iff x+iy=x-iy\iff\left\{
\begin{array}{ccl}x=x\\y=-y\end{array}\right.\iff y =0\iff z=x$$
So $z=\bar{z}$ implies $z$ is real.

Answer (score 2):

$0$ is the only number in the reals which is equal to its own negative. The proof showed both equalities because it is proving an if and only if statement.

Answer (score 0):

Just a thought. what happen if $z=\cos(i^2)$;
then, 
derivative of $\cos(x^2)$;
then, Taylor series
compile it up into sigma form,
then,
maybe 
a variable becomes a real, as a sequence, with endless fluctuation as a function of $\cos$;
then,
maybe, if lucky
become a irrational number, I mean, at least, it is real number;
e limit
compile it up into a symble,

You got your own symble :)

Best luck:)