# When is a complex number $z$ real?

Tags: complex-analysis

When discussing the order relation on $\mathbb{C}$, it is said that such a statement as $z_1 < z_2$ where $z_1, z_2 \in \mathbb{C}$ is meaningless, unless $z_1$ and $z_2$ are real.

My question is, when will a complex number $z$ be real? I know that if $\bar{z}$ is the conjugate of $z$, then

$$z + \bar{z} = 2a$$
$$z\bar{z} = a^2+b^2$$

produce real numbers, but it is easy to add $0i$ to either equation to produce a complex number.

Comment: "strictly real" just means $z=a+0i$ i.e. $z$ happens to lie on the "real axis" of the complex plane. That has no effect on closure of complexes under addition/multiplication.

Answer (score 2):

A complex is real when its imaginary part is $0$. This is the case iff $z=\bar{z}$

Answer (score 2):

A complex number is strictly real iff $z=\overline{z}$

Comment: The terminology 'strictly real' appears in your answer and [@coffeemath](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1811581/when-is-a-complex-number-z-real#comment3702130_1811581)'s comment.  Why?  That is, what is gained by 'strictly real' over just 'real'?  (I could understand the useage of 'strictly complex' for a non-real complex number, in which case 'strictly complex' is not equivalent to 'complex'; but this definition of 'strictly real' *is* equivalent to 'real'.)

Comment: because I like to refer to a *real* number as an element of $\mathbb{R}$... so $z\in\mathbb{C}$ with imaginary part $0$ is not formally a *real* number

Comment: An element $z \in \mathbb C$ with imaginary part $0$ *does* lie in $\mathbb R$, and hence is real.  I think that distinguishing "an element that is presented as belonging to $\mathbb C$, and that happens to belong to its subset $\mathbb R$" from "an element that is presented as belonging to $\mathbb R$" is not in accord with standard usage.  (I want to mumble something about extensionality versus intentionality here, but that may be abusing the terminology.)

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/389897/the-set-of-real-numbers-is-a-subset-of-the-set-of-complex-numbers

Is this sufficient? Look at the second answer

Comment: To be sure, there are ways of constructing $\mathbb C$ according to which $\mathbb R$ is not literally a subset, but I think that "$\mathbb R$ is not a subset of $\mathbb C$" is also not in accord with standard usage.  (See, for example, the comment http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/389897/the-set-of-real-numbers-is-a-subset-of-the-set-of-complex-numbers#comment834395_389904 on the answer http://math.stackexchange.com/a/389904/87579 to which I think you refer.)  By the same token, one might say that the real number $1$ is not a natural number, which might not be wrong but is confusing.

Comment: Again... I am not saying that you must follow my way; but I just like to emphasize the fact that we are dealing with complex numbers with imaginary part $0$, by using the *strictly* thingy...

Comment: This is a good point, and I'm sorry if I sounded argumentative.  I actually meant to address, and should explicitly have done so, my follow-up mainly to @BenedictVoltaire , to avoid any confusion with others who might use just 'real' in the same circumstance.

Answer (score 2):

Complex numbers are real iff $z=\bar{z}$. For $z=a+bi$ we also say that $z$ is real if $b=Im(z)=0$.

Related : [Proving complex z is real iff $z=\bar{z}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/331113/proving-that-a-complex-number-z-is-real)

Comment: "Adding $0i$ doesn't produce a complex number as in this case $b=0$."  Or, rather, it *does* produce a complex number, but one that happens also to be a real number.

Comment: Yes thank you @LSpice, this is due to the fact that the field of complex numbers includes the field of real numbers as a subfield

Comment: @David_Shmij $-1\neq|-1|$, but -1 is real. Am I missing something?

Comment: @Polygon Yes, absolute value is not the same thing as conjugate.

Comment: @David_Shmij Oh nevermind. For some strange reason I saw the horizontal line over $z$ as an absolute value sign. My apologies.

Comment: @Polygon No worries!